# Variance on operations of random variables

Tags: variance, random-variable

After reading a bit on the wiki, I though I could find the variance of my variable, but I'm getting confused...
Let's assume we have two random variables, $A$ and $B$ which are uncorrelated.
Now, what is the variance of:

$D = f*(A-B)+B$

My problem is, from this formula I get:

$Var(D) = f^{2}(Var(A)+Var(B)) + Var(B)$

However, the initial definition of D can be rewritten as:

$D = f*A + (1-f)*B$

which in turns gives

$Var(D) = f^{2}Var(A) + (1-f)^{2}Var(B)$

Maybe I'm seeing wrong, but the two variance formulas are different

Comment: Is $f$ a constant? Does $*$ denote multiplication?

Comment: Yes, $f$ is constant and $*$ stands for multiplication

Comment: I think it is a bit confusing. `$\cdot$` is better suited than `*` in this case. $f$ suggests a function, I would have used $c$ instead. But now that there already is an answer using the same notation, let is stay.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $A$ and $B$ are uncorrelated, $A-B$ and $B$ certainly are correlated. Therefore, you cannot write:

$Var(D) = f^{2}(Var(A)+Var(B)) + Var(B)$

Instead:

$Var(D) = f^{2}(Var(A)+Var(B)) + Var(B) + 2fCovar(A-B,B)$
$Var(D) = f^{2}(Var(A)+Var(B)) + Var(B) - 2fVar(B)$

Which gives, after factorization :

$Var(D) = f^{2}Var(A) + (1-f)^{2}Var(B)$

Comment: Can you explain how you remove $Covar(A-B, B)$?

Comment: @DiogoSantos $Covar(A-B,B) = -Var(B)$ since $A$ and $B$ are uncorrelated

Comment: But why does the variance of $A$ disappears?