# Variance of frequency

Tags: variance, random-variable

Variable $X$ is a random variable with know $E(X)$ and $Var(X)$. Variable $Y$ is also a random variable with know $E(Y)$ and $Var(Y)$ and $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

What is the variance and expected value of 
$\dfrac{X}{X+Y}$?

The expected value looks simple, but the variance not... I found this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/40713/calculating-the-variance-of-the-ratio-of-random-variables), and from there the only problem is to get 
$cov(X, X+Y)$, which I have no idea how to calculate...

Comment: Any assumptions on the distribution of $X$ and $Y$

Comment: They are both geometric distributions. This is related with my question [here](http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/50703/modeling-population-growth-variance). However, I'm also interested in the general answer, without assumptions, for curiosity sake :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt there is a general formula for any distribution :

```
n <- 100000

x <- rpois(n, 1)
y <- rchisq(n, df = 2)/2

mean(x/(x+y))
sd(x/(x+y))

x2 <- rexp(n,1)
y2 <- rexp(n,1)

mean(x2/(x2+y2))
sd(x2/(x2+y2))
```

Though the expected values and variances are all the same:

```
> mean(x/(x+y))
[1] 0.4179734
> sd(x/(x+y))
[1] 0.3608732
```

And:

```
> mean(x2/(x2+y2))
[1] 0.4996955
> sd(x2/(x2+y2))
[1] 0.2889206
```

Comment: In the post I linked, there seams to be a more general answer... Given your answer in [here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/229502/variance-on-operations-of-random-variables?rq=1) I guess I can calculate $cov(X, X+Y) = var(X)$ and use that.